# Button disabled with MotionCaptcha

Tags: jquery, button, mobile

Well, I'm from Mexico, so, I'm sorry for my bad English.

I'm doing a form with JQuery Mobile and I'm using MotionCaptcha (http://www.josscrowcroft.com/demos/motioncaptcha/) app. 
I have a problem with a submit button, it doesn't disabled or enabled itself. At the beginning, the button is disabled (all right), but, if I introduce the right captcha, it doesn't turned into a enabled button until I refresh the captcha. Then, when the button is enabled, and I click on it, it doesn't turned into a disabled button. 
I have noticed that the problem emerges when I add the JQuery Mobile files.

Someone could tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

while using MotionCaptcha with jQuery Mobile I've also faced with that problem.
The problem is in jQuery Mobile which adds its classes and data attributes to the input to which you've added  `disabled="disabled"` attribute and while on client you delete disabled attribute the other classes are not deleted. Solution I've found is just add the following line into the jQuery.motionCaptcha.js  - onSuccess callback function just after the

```
// Enable the submit button:
$submit.prop('disabled', false);
```

insert next line

```
$submit.button('enable');
```